# window.print function in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, printing

I have a `window.print()` that is intended to print the displayed contents of `modal`.

```
@media print {
  @page {
  size: 120.76mm 150.16mm; 
  /* you can also specify margins here: */
  margin: 0;
}
```

The output of this in chrome browser print dialog is the `printable content` is located at the center of the default set paper.

**Addional details:**

When I change the destination to `Save as PDF` instead of the `Default Printer` expected output is displayed as set on the `CSS media print`.

**Edit:**

How I can do something like the output of `Save as PDF` into the `Default Printer`?

**Images:**

Default Printer Output
[image: Sample of Default Printer Output]
Save as PDF Output
[image: Sample of Save as PDF Output]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @epascarello, sorry for that. I updated the post and added question and some images. thanks